# Why converge in probability introduces epsilon in its definition?

Tags: probability

According to wiki:

a.s. converge: $$\Pr(\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}X_n=X)=1$$

converge in probability: $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\Pr(|X_n-X|>\epsilon)=0$$

What about $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\Pr(X_n=X)=0$? (Compared to a.s. converge, I think it is more intuitive to have such a definition.)
Why converge in probability introduce the $\epsilon$ in its definition?

Comment: Think of the case $X_n=\frac 1 n, X=0$.

Comment: Thanks. In this case, $Pr(X_n=X)$ will always be 0. I think I got it. Moving the $limit$ out of $Pr(\dot)$ don't cover such cases where $X_n(\omega)$ approaches $X(\omega)$   on all events $\omega$ but always not equal to $X(\omega)$. In order to describe such cases, $\epsilon$ is introduced to describe the "approach of $X_n(\omega )$ to $X(\omega)$

Comment: For infinity, use `\infty`, not `\inf`.

Comment: Thank you for the correction

Answer (score 0):

After some research and rethinking, I believe I figure it out.

Translating the limit language to plain words helps undertanding.

**a.s. converge**: for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists large enough N so that for all n>N, $Pr(|X_n-X|>\epsilon)=0$.

**Converge in distribution**: for any $\epsilon > 0, \delta > 0$, there exists large enough N so that for all n>N, $Pr(|X_n-X|>\epsilon)<\delta$.

The difference is for any $\epsilon > 0$, a.s. converge gaurantees there exists big enough N so that it is almost impossible that $|X_n-X|>\epsilon$, however, converge in distribution leave open possbility of $|X_n-X|>\epsilon$.

So it is farely natural to have a $\epsilon$ in the brackets, just as in a.s. converge. Converge in probability is  a weaker version of a.s. converge.

As @Kavi Rama Murthy comments, to drop the $\epsilon$ excludes such cases where the sequence of r.v. converges to X apparently.

**What confused me is just the notation of limit: there actually a $\epsilon$ in the definition of a.s. converge.**

Comment: I suggest that you edit your question, instead of posting this as an answer.

Comment: @José Carlos Santos
 I think it is ok to answer my question if I think I have find the right anwser. I want to share my research and thought result. Can you explain why I should edit my question not anwser it? Is it because one should not anwser his own question or I am just not qualified (and how can I know I'm qualified to answer a question?) or my anwser is wrong?    I'm new to stackexchange. Thanks!

Comment: Then I misunderstood your answer. What you wrote seemed to me to be an improvement upon the answer. But if it is an answer, forget what I wrote.

Comment: Yes, it is an answer. Anyway, thank you for reminding me.